# Wso2 API to Windows Authenticated OData API

Tags: wso2, windows-authentication, wso2-api-manager

Evaluating Wso2 API Manager.  I have dozens of various APIs that have been developed by several groups over the past few years, all authenticate with IIS windows authentication.

How can I configure Wso2 API Manager to call a backend OData API that is expecting Windows Authentication in the request?

I don't actually need to pass-through authentication from the calling user, I'd be okay specifying a dedicated service account that API Manager always used to call the backend services.

Answer (score 0):

API Manager supports NTLM authentication. You can follow the sample in APIM_HOME/samples/NTLMGrantClient. This [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=45967315) explains this. Also please follow this [blog](http://chathurikaerandi.blogspot.com/2015/05/testing-ntlm-grant-type-with-api-manager.html).

Comment: as described in the blog, does this mean that we must also use Identity Server?

Comment: IN here Identity Server is used for AD configuration. You can use the relevant AD.

Answer (score 0):

The Endpoint Auth Type "Windows Authentification" is not supported by API Manager. You might want to consider activating "Basic" or "Digest" authentification on your service in IIS (both of them are supported by API Manager).
see: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Basic+Auth